# Move Checkout Agreements from top to end of the page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, terms-and-conditions

I am trying hard to move the checkout agreements in the last Checkout Step from the top of the page to bottom, right above the "order now" and "edit cart" buttons. But without success.
Right now they are placed at top of the

```
frontend/mytheme/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml.
```

But moving or commenting out the

```
<block type="checkout/agreements" name="checkout.onepage.agreements" as="agreements" template="checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml"/>
```

in the checkout.xml of "mytheme" does not seem to have any effect at all.

The only effect seems to have renaming the `agreements.phtml` to `_old`, then they are gone completely.

What is the problem there? I just would like to move the agreements to the end of the page, before the order buttons.

But be very nice if anyone could give me some support on this.

Regards.

---

Yes, the line `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('agreements') ?>` is placed exactly like so.

What i do not understand is, if i comment out this line within the info.phtml and within the checkout.xml at base path and path of "mytheme" the agreements are still displayed at top of review.phtml.

Only if i rename both agreements.phtml within base and "mytheme"-path to like "_old" they are gone.
But moving the line `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('agreements') ?>` to place agreements at end of the page doesn´t work at all.

Do i have to do some configuration in the **onepagecontroller.php**-file to get this work?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('agreements') ?>
```

is placed inside the block with id **checkout-review-submit** before the block with id **review-buttons-container** in 
*app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml*

**EDIT**

The route *app/design/frontend/base/default* is the default theme of Magento. If you install a custom theme, check in the **info.phtml** or **review.phtml** of your theme.